# Open component view from code behind

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using mvc 6 and I would like to "open" component view by using some button onClick.

I can display it by using

```
<div id="DialogDiv">
   @Component.Invoke("MyComponent");
</div>
```

but I would like to do it so that some button onclick method would call that invoke method and give that div as a reference. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to render component by using ajax request. Since MVC6-beta7 you can do this by utilising View Component Action Result:

See:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2338

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/releases/tag/6.0.0-beta7

The idea for your scenario will be to use JavaScript and call action in controller which will return **ViewComponentResult** and then render result of that action into your page. You can do this by using jQuery, so it will look like:

```
$.get("/YourController/YourAction",function(data){
    $("#DialogDiv").html(data);
});
```